# Updating excel values in data grid view on certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to fetch a row value from an excel sheet in data grid view in winform.

I’m able to display the entire excel sheet in the datagridview. But, I need to display particular rows in the grid based on a current date condition.

```
 public DataTable ReadExcel2(string fileName, string fileExt)
     {
        string connectionstring ;
        DataTable dtexcel2 = new DataTable();
        connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [POSFailures$]  WHERE Date=@date");
        oconn.Connection = connection;
        try
        {
            oconn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

            sda.Fill(dtexcel2);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return dtexcel2;
    }
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Hi Nanda! It would be very helpful if you could show us your code, and then identify exactly what's not working.

Comment: Hi Casey, I’m able to display the entire excel sheet in data grid. But I’m not even able to proceed with the if condition. I’ve no idea how to take that further. I’ve tried few after searching a lot in google. But nothing worked.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But what I'm saying is... if you want someone there to help, you are going to need to give us a lot more details.  The correct way to ask a quesiton here is to say "Here is my code [then show code].  This is what I expect to happen [then explain desired outcome]. But this is what is actually happening [explain the actual outcome]."

Comment: Thank you.. I’ll share my code

Comment: I’ve shared my code.. do help

Comment: Comment 1 of 2: Hi Nanda.  If you recall, in an earlier comment, I said:  "The correct way to ask a question here is to say "Here is my code [then show code]. This is what I expect to happen [then explain the desired outcome]. But this is what is actually happening [explain the actual outcome]."   You've now done the first part you have shared the code.  But you still have not told us what this code is expected to do, nor have you told us what it actually does.  Do you get an error when you execute this code?  Or does it run with no error but gives you the wrong data?

Comment: Comment 2 of 2: Also, I also don't have access to your excel file, so I can't test the code. It would be good if you could show us what the excel file looks like so we could maybe reproduce it on our side.  Remember, we can't see what's in your head, and we are not sitting at the desk next to you.

Comment: Sorry about it. The excel file contains data corresponding to current date which will be stored in the first column and rest of the data in the next rows and columns. I mean the first column will have the dates. But here, I’m getting the data of all dates. I need to get the row data of current date in the excel.

Comment: Ok, so you ARE getting back some data. That's good to know.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the Date value in one of the rows? Is it a Date and a Time, or just a date? How is it formated?

Comment: It is formatted in mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Ok, but what is the actual value?

Comment: 08/28/2019 current date

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening here is that the Date parameter is not being honored, as you are getting back all of the rows.  So, I used Google to figure out how to properly add parameters when using `OleDbConnection`. I found this:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbCommand_Parameters

Using the example on that page, try changing your code to this:

```
string connectionstring;
DataTable dtexcel2 = new DataTable();
connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [POSFailures$]  WHERE Date = ?");
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), OleDbType.Date));
command.Connection = connection;
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

    sda.Fill(dtexcel2);
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Please note that i've not tested this, so I can't promise it will work. But, the main point is... the answer is out there!  You just need to go looking for it.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. But after using your help, I'm getting Invalidcastexception - The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects at command.Parameters.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
command.Connection = connection;

Comment: Ok, we need to make the parameter a date. Hang on.

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer.  Again, as I don't have your Excel file I can't really test this.

Comment: Can I know where exactly did you make the change?

Comment: I don't see any changes in the code you edited recently. I think it's not updated

Comment: this line changed: command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), OleDbType.Date));
command.Connection = connection;
try

Comment: Now,the error is - No value given for one or more required parameters at sda.Fill(dtexcel2);
connection.Close();
Do we need to pass any parameter? Again, a great thanks!